# vb.net my.Settings.Reload() not working

Tags: vb.net

I am implementing a mechanism to detect a corrupt `user.config` file in `vb` at application startup.

I do this at the start of the application before initializing anything.

If an `exception` is thrown while trying to access it, I replace the file with a backup last known good copy.

After replacing the bad file and physically checking that we have a good file I run the code :

```
My.Settings.Reload()
```

This should as per definition, reload the new file. However its not working and the application is still crashing due to a bad config file.

> What is the reload() method NOT loading the new config file.

Comment: My crystal ball says there's a bug in the code that replaces user.config.  It might be right, given that it is so difficult to find the proper path to the file.  You can't get it out of LocalFileSettingsProvider.  Post code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way I could think to run it is in a new thread that isn't on the UI.

```
Dim t as new threading.thread(addressof tt)

sub tt()
'replace config file and reload
end sub
```

Then just use t.Start()

Comment: Tried this but it didnt work. Apparently what seems to be happening is that once the  System.Configuration throws an error, you cant call the my.settings.reload() method for the current instance. Event when I forked and did everything on a different Thread, I was still referring to the same  instance of my.settings. My current solution that works is to do this check as one of the first operations at app startup, if the user.config is corrupted, I replace it, end current instance of the app and start a new one.

Comment: If it's not too much hassle for the end user, you could just make a separate exe or batch file to run that fixes the error.